# Best practice to map webservice endpoint in client

Tags: java, spring, web-services, client

this question is more of a design/architecture question. Let's say I have a server application that provides Spring-based webservices and a client application. So currently I have a few Java classes on the client side where the endpoint of the service is hardcoded (e.g. http://myserver/some/webservice).
What is a good way to map the client side properly with the webservice? Just off the top of my head: is there a library that helps evaluate URLs with parameters and maps them to the properties of a POJO using reflection?

Comment: what kind of webservices do you have here? SOAP ? REST ?...

Comment: They're REST webservices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your question, 2 options pop into my head:

1) [Eureka- Service Discovery for Spring Cloud.](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka)

It can help you by giving your client the Eureka URL and the Eureka will supply the client with the desired service URL. so if there the server is going down Eureka can point the client to a back up server (it will be seamless to the client) or even different URL's to different services on the same server.

2) [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/)

A configuration service that contains the URL's in the DB, the client will pull those URLs from there and will make the calls to a configurable URI's.
Spring allow you to update those URL's in the DB and it will use spring cloud config to push the new URL's down to the clients without any downtime... (might fit you better if you are not interested in load balancing and other features provided by Eureka)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks promising so far (after having a quick glance). However, I'm not sure if that really covers what I need. Let's assume I have a webservice like http://myserver/some/webservice/{id}. For some reason another parameter is added on the service side. It would be great if there was some utility that would read the address from a config file and maps the parameter to POJO fields

Comment: you can use a configuration file with: `@Value("${config.name}")` above the member in order to read it from the configuration file. If you will use the Spring Cloud Config, you can also add `@RefreshScope` and `@Configuration` on the class so once you update the values on the configuration service they will be automatically changed in the client side.